# How comparing two identical tables work in sql?

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

It is very interesting how SQL compares two identical tables. For example, here is a schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Sailors (
   sid INTEGER,   
   sname CHAR(20), 
   rating INTEGER, 
   age REAL,
   PRIMARY KEY (sid));

INSERT INTO Sailors VALUES
    (1, 'Hu', 10, 22),
    (2, 'Gat', 11, 39),
    (3, 'Ej', 1, 27),
    (4, 'Pon', 5, 19);
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sailors S 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
 (SELECT * 
  FROM Sailors S2 
  WHERE S.age > S2.age);
```

And it returns the youngest sailor. Can you explain me step by step how does it work?

Comment: The schemas for boats and reserves in your question are irrelevant. Your query is simply asking to find all records from the sailors table where there does not exist a record in the same table whose age is less than the records selected (the query says where the current age is greater than the test - the same test in reverse). The only record(s) for which this will find a result is/are the records with the minimum age.

Answer (score 0):

For each sailor, it does a [subquery](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php) to check if there are any sailors who are younger (where S.age > S2.age). If there are, they're filtered out (where not exists).

This can be done simpler and faster by finding the minimum age and then selecting all sailors with it.

```
select *
from sailors
where age = (
  select min(age) from sailors
);
```